# UIImage being stretched when copying from UIPasteboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have a valid image with the right content size, however I have noticed when I try to paste this image to WhatsApp or through iMessage the image get's significantly stretched. I have looked at the image and it seams to be fine on UIImageview, but somehow it gets stretched in particular to outer controls.

Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When copying an image make sure to modify the imageView's mode. There are different modes, like Aspect Fit, Scale to fill and so on.

If let's say the image is 500x300 and your imageView's size is set to 350x230 and mode to Scale to fill, it will end up stretched. Try to fiddle around and see what works for you. Most of the times i choose Aspect Fit.

Try that out.

BTW. You can find it under inspection tab in design editor or set it programmatically if you choose so.

Comment: I am actually trying to copy image from textView. I made a snapshot of the visible content of the textView and converted to an image. Now when I paste that Image to whatsapp or iMessage, it gets stretched.